# Unable to get rsyslog to save only msg without timestamp

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

When I have the default settings, my logs are like this:

```
2020-12-01T18:34:06+02:00 10.132.90.194 {"wfd_successful_hits_sec": "0", "sql_hits_sec_max": "0", "timestamp": "2020/12/01 18:34:01", "connection_sec_max": "1922", "http_hits_sec_max": "1106", "http_hits_sec": "106", "wfd_successful_hits_sec_max": "0", "sql_hits_sec": "0", "sql_audit_phase2_events_sec_max": "0", "hdfs_hits_sec": "0", "connection_sec": "26"}
```

But as soon as I try to have it write just the msg, it fails.

and gives me the msg with the beginning clipped.

```
"0", "timestamp": "2020/12/01 18:34:01", "connection_sec_max": "1922", "http_hits_sec_max": "1106", "http_hits_sec": "106", "wfd_successful_hits_sec_max": "0", "sql_hits_sec": "0", "sql_audit_phase2_events_sec_max": "0", "hdfs_hits_sec": "0", "connection_sec": "26"}
```

My Rsyslog Config:

```
$template OnlyMsg,"%msg:2:2048%\n"
$template CustomLog,"/logs/host-%fromhost%-%$year%-%$month%.log"

local5.*                                               ?CustomLog;OnlyMsg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input line is not really standardised for syslog, so for example the string `{"wfd_successful_hits_sec":` is probably being mistaken for the tag, and the msg field is after this.

You can probably simply use the `rawmsg` property instead of `msg`, as it contains the whole input line (after the priority). Try a starting offset of about 40 characters to account for the timestamp and ip address. If you have ip addresses of different lengths you can use a regexp instead to match the start.

Comment: Hi, I ended up using regex match.The below regex worked and I managed to achieve what I wanted

$Template tpl,"%rawmsg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:(\{.*)--end%\n"